# Why is the top of an empty stack a table in lua?

Tags: c, lua

I thought the documentation of lua_settop() was quite clear:

> void lua_settop (lua_State *L, int index);
>
> Accepts any acceptable index, or 0, and sets the stack top to this index. If the
>   new top is larger than the old one, then the new elements are filled with nil. If
>   index is 0, then all stack elements are removed.

...and yet, this code:

```
lua_settop(L, 0);
top = lua_gettop(L);
if (lua_isnoneornil(L, top)) {
  printf("Invalid stack (nil)");
}
else {
  // WTF?
  printf("? %d -> %s", top, lua_typename(L, lua_type(L, top)));
}
```

Yields:

```
? 0 -> table
```

What gives?

How can I check if the stack is empty? Using (lua_gettop(L) == 0)?

If so, why is there even a lua_isnone() call?

Comment: Yes, you check whether the stack is empty with `lua_gettop(L) == 0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is trivially answered by the docs for [`lua_gettop`](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_gettop):

> Returns the index of the top element in the stack. Because indices
>   start at 1, this result is equal to the number of elements in the
>   stack (**and so 0 means an empty stack**).

Comment: ie. lua_isnone() and lua_isnoneornil() are useless functions. fantastic documentation.

Comment: @Doug: Why are they useless? Certainly `lua_isnoneornil` is quite handy, because it returns true if the value exists but is `nil`. Which checking the size of the stack won't help with. `lua_isnone` is a convenience function. Just because you *can* replace a function call with code doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: `lua_isnoneornil()` is intended to make dealing with optional or missing arguments more convenient. You use it on stack slots that are greater than 0 and less than or equal to `lua_gettop()`. If you ask it about stack slots that are *not on the stack* it will return nonsense.

Comment: The key here is the unhelpfully distantly documented fact that "Note that 0 is never an acceptable index."

Answer (score 1):

Just for reference for anyone else who stumbles on this question, the other answer to this question is, from the lua docs:

Most query functions accept as indices any value inside the available stack space, that is, indices up to the maximum stack size you have set through lua_checkstack. Such indices are called acceptable indices. More formally, we define an acceptable index as follows:

```
 (index < 0 && abs(index) <= top) ||
 (index > 0 && index <= stackspace)
```

**Note that 0 is never an acceptable index.**

If lau_gettop() returns 0, is_none() and isnoneornil() cannot be called because 0 is not an acceptable index.